# Amazon Lex session attributes web console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, session-variables, alexa-skills-kit, aws-lex

I just started to create a simple chat bot using Amazon Lex. I would like to use some `session` attributes. Basically, my bot needs to call many lambda functions passing a `user-id` (that will change, not sure yet how to set it). I'd like to set the `user-id` as a session attribute, so it will be passed as parameter to every function. However, I can't find a way to do it directly through the web console (interface). Is it possible or can it be done only via the `CLI`?

Comment: If i understand correctly, you have a LEX bot deployed on your webpage and u want to pass your webpage level attributes to lambda function via ur lex bot when user submits to an intent?

Comment: Have you tried: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/context-mgmt.html

Comment: Yes I did check it, but they assume the `session-attributes` are already set. I don't know how to create them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I integrate AWS Lex chatbot to my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43059930/how-do-i-integrate-aws-lex-chatbot-to-my-website)

Comment: No, I am looking to how to set session attributes via the web interface...totally different than that question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to set the user-id from lex dashboard. Lex is creating random user-id and passing it to lambda function. I have created Lex bot and integrated with website and called the lex from website using aws postText function where i have given my own user-id and session attritubes. You can refer in [aws postText reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostText.html)

Comment: I am interested as to how you did this. I get what you mean but i had a hard time implementing it. Hoping for some clarity and help. :D